# unknown cbyeditor in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

The `biblatex-chicago` extension yields unknown **cbyeditor** and **cbytranslator** terms when `footcite` is used and probably the `french` option in `babel`. The main file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib} 
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}      
\begin{document}
\section{Text}
Text\footcite{Brisson}
\section{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[keyword=TradPlat,heading=bibempty]
\end{document}
```

and the `Bibliography.bib` file is:

```
@inbook{Brisson,
  author = {Luc Brisson},
  title = {Les traditions platonicienne et aristotélicienne},
  address = {Paris},
  publisher = {Presses Universitaires de France},
  year = {1998},
  editor = {Monique Canto-Sperber},
  pages = {595-671},
  keywords = {TradPlat},
  series = {Premier cycle},
  booktitle = {Philosophie grecque}
}
```

The result with this **cbyeditor** term is given below. This has already been reported on the net with no clear solution to my knowledge. I would say that this related to the `french.lbx` file.

[image]

Comment: why were the comments provided here removed? I think they were still useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{cms-french}` to your preamble. See section 6 of the `biblatex-chicago` manual for details.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{cms-french}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{Brisson,
  author = {Luc Brisson},
  title = {Les traditions platonicienne et aristotélicienne},
  address = {Paris},
  publisher = {Presses Universitaires de France},
  year = {1998},
  editor = {Monique Canto-Sperber},
  pages = {595-671},
  keywords = {TradPlat},
  series = {Premier cycle},
  booktitle = {Philosophie grecque}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

\section{Text}

Text\footcite{Brisson}

\printbibliography[keyword=TradPlat,heading=bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: interesting but it looks like it destroys the small capitalization of last names which is recommended in french typography.

Comment: @pluton I updated my answer.