# Translator name in biblatex-chicago -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: biblatex, biber, chicago-style

Been struggling with this for... too long.

This (template I found) works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber
]{biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{danish}{cms-danish}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{gardner1999,
  title =        "Den intelligente skole",
  subtitle =     "Gardner i praksis",
  author =       "Howard Gardner",
  date =         "1999",
  usere =    "Multiple Intelligenses",
  origdate =     "1993",
  origpubliser = "FooPub",
  origlocation = "USA",
  publisher =    "Gyldendal",
  origlanguage = "english",
  edition =      "1",
  translator =   "Strandberg, Kurt",
  location =     "Kbenhavn",
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{
      cbytranslator = {Oversataf}
}
\begin{document}
foo\footcite[1]{gardner1999}




\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My own file, on the other hand does not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}


@Book{gardner1999,
  title =        "Den intelligente skole",
  subtitle =     "Gardner i praksis",
  author =       "Howard Gardner",
  date =         "1999",
  usere =        "Multiple Intelligenses",
  origdate =     "1993",
  origlanguage = "english",
  publisher =    "Gyldendal",
  edition =      "1",
  translator = "Strandberg, Kurt",
  location =     "Kbenhavn",
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo\footcite[1]{gardner1999}
\newpage
\nocite{*} %% vis alt i bibliografien
\printbibliography %% Historian 
\end{document}
```

It gives me the error:

```
 Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'cbytranslator' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'gardner1999' on input line 34.
```

and this ugly output:
[image]

I can't seem to find out what's wrong -- I hope you guys can help!

Comment: And what happens when you comment out the `\DefineBibliographyStrings` line in the file that works.  And (less relevantly to the error you're reporting) what about the language mapping?

Comment: You need at least the `\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{cbytranslator = {Oversat af}}` chunk of code in your own file. Otherwise `biblatex` does not know what `cbyeditor` means (it might also not be too bad to include `\DeclareLanguageMapping{danish}{cms-danish}`, so other custom bibstrings by `biblatex-chicago` are also known to `biblatex`).

Comment: You're right: 
`\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{cbytranslator = {Oversat af}} `did the trick. Don't know how I missed it.

Comment: @Johannes_B Done.

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard As you noticed, there is still some missing translations for the danish language. You can contribute and help other fellow users by contributing the translations to respective author.

Answer (score 2):

Currently `biblatex-chicago` does not come with a Danish language version file (English, Finnish, French, German, Icelandic and Norwegian seem to be supported at this moment), so its custom bib strings are not known to `biblatex`.

We will have to define them ourselves via

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{
      cbytranslator = {Oversataf}
}
```

but in order for this to work, we need to tell `biblatex` about this new bibstring in the first place by

```
\NewBibliographyString{cbytranslator}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{gardner1999,
  title =        "Den intelligente skole",
  subtitle =     "Gardner i praksis",
  author =       "Howard Gardner",
  date =         "1999",
  usere =        "Multiple Intelligenses",
  origdate =     "1993",
  origlanguage = "english",
  publisher =    "Gyldendal",
  edition =      "1",
  translator = "Strandberg, Kurt",
  location =     "Kbenhavn",
}
\end{filecontents}

\NewBibliographyString{cbytranslator}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{cbytranslator = {Oversat af}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Foo\footcite[1]{gardner1999}
\nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you might run into trouble with any other of the numerous bibstrings defined in the supplementary `lbx` files, which you are still missing here.
So what you are really after is a Danish version of `cms-american.lbx`.
If such a file exists you would go about using it like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59338/35864).